# How can I use LINQ to find a DataGridView row?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

Is there any way to use a LINQ style query to find a DataGridView row?  I am trying to find the one bound to a specific object and highlight it.

```
MyDatagrid.Rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.DataBoundItem == myItem).Selected = true;
```

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to cast to `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` since `DataGridViewRowCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`:

```
using System.Linq;

MyDatagrid.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.DataBoundItem == myItem).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who came here looking for the VB-version, Lee's answer translates to:

```
MyDatagrid.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.DataBoundItem Is myItem).Selected = True
```

Furthermore, if you're like me, and are using this to find your `DataGridViewRow` from your bound `DataTable.DataRow` (`DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable`), then you can access it like this:

```
Dim MyDataRowSearch() As DataRow = MyDataTable.Select("SomeColumn = SomeValue")
If MyDataRowSearch.Count = 1 Then
  MyDataGrid.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) DirectCast(r.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row Is MyDataRowSearch(0)).Selected = True
End If
```

This is much more efficient than looping through your `DataGridView` looking for matching values.