# set selected row datagridview by cell's value

Tags: c#, winforms

how to set selected row on `dataGridView` by a string?

example..

[image]

when form_loaded...i want that `dataGridView` with cell "LSN" is selected

so if i have a `string text = "LSN"`

then that table's row with cell value "LSN" is selected..

i usually use `dataGridView1.Rows[3].Selected = true;` to set selected row in datagridview..

but how can i do that if i dont know row's index and only know a string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to iterate through each row of the DataGridView until you find the value you want. You can then select the row and break out of the loop.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // 0 is the column index
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals("LSN"))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this example but it should give you the right idea.

Answer (score 4):

Please try below code...

```
string txtSearchValue="LSN";
int rowIndex = -1; 

DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r=>r.Cells["SystemId"].Value.ToString().Equals(txtSearchValue))
    .First();
rowIndex = row.Index; 

dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

without LINQ:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(txtSearchValue))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq maybe?

[How can I use LINQ to find a DataGridView row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098071/how-can-i-use-linq-to-find-a-datagridview-row)

dataGridView1.Rows

> `dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => x.Kode == "LSN").FirstorDefault()`